# How to change wp-admin/edit.php categories filter to a multiselect?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using GoDaddy hosting, with WordPress Managed plan, so I can't edit anything in `wp-admin/` or `wp-includes/` folder, the only folder I've permission is `wp-content/`.

I tried to look it on google, and tried to find the plugins, I found this plugin `Post Filter Multiselect` but it doesn't working anymore, my WordPress version is `4.9.5` and the plugin were not updated since 9 month ago. So I tried another plugins but neither of them are working.

If I want to add this with `themes` or `plugins` how to do it? because I can't found the answer, thank you.

What I want is to make the `wp-admin/edit.php` categories filter be a multiselect, because in 1 post, there are so many categories, so to narrow it down, it need multiple categories. and there are a lot of categories, around 50 categories.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other plugins like [search & filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/) ? I haven't used it myself but it seems to be what you are looking for. Also, have you tried contacting the support to see if they could grant you access to the folder?

Comment: yeah I already that as well, but it's not for the `edit.php` in the wp-admin, I need the one for edit.php filter.

Comment: I already asked them, but they won't give it, because I'm on Managed WordPress plan.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is slightly a sledgehammer-to-crack-nut approach, but you could install the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin and create a **Taxonomy** field. You can select an **Appearance** of Multiple Values > **Multi Select** and make sure that **Create Terms**, **Save Terms** and **Load Terms** are all true so that your categories are synced properly with the post. Finally, in the field group settings you can select the checkbox to hide the normal categories meta box.

It's one that's worked for me in the past without requiring extra plugins (since I already use ACF).

Comment: So using this method you mention, I don't have to edit the core files right? I can do it from custom plugins?

Comment: You should NEVER edit the core files as your edits will get wiped out next time WP updates itself, and it will cause any security plugins you might have to flag them as modified. Yes, this method works perfectly for me, but then I already use ACF for other things.

Comment: I don't understand about using this ACF, can you show me how to do it? because I can't find the option you mention

Comment: So with this method, I can edit this [categories filter](https://i.imgur.com/TRiuLwW.png) to a multiselect?

Comment: Please see their documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/